# Google Analytics - Discrepancy between Event and Goal numbers

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics-events

Our goal is set up very simply - track all events with Action = "Complete".
When looking at the event numbers for any given time period, they are always a couple units higher than the goal counts. Example: 1,026 Total Events for Action = Complete, and 1,003 Unique Events

[image: 1,026 Total Events for Action: Complete, and 1,003 Unique Events]

991 Goal completions for the same time period.
[image: 991 Goal completions for the same time period]

Here is the setup of the goal - it's very simple. Only checks for Action = "Complete"
[image: Goal Setup - check for Action = "Complete"]

Any explanation for this? Does goal completion determine unique sessions differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytics increments the Unique Events metric by 1 the first time during a session that it receives an event with a unique combination of Category/Action/Label.

A defined goal is track once per visit.

So if you have for example these two events in a session:

```
- Event 1
category: Form
action: Complete
label: Sign up

- Event 2
category: Form
action: Complete
label: Comment
```

In Analytics they will be counted as 2 unique events but only 1 goal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So if the same user fills out two different forms in one visit, that means that the goal will be hit once. I think the solution would be here to create more specific goals per form.

Comment: Yes, but max goals number available in a view are 20.